# c++ and multi pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple problem with pointers. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef float RtPoint[3]; 
    RtPoint** b = new RtPoint*[4];
    b[0] = (RtPoint*)new RtPoint;
    RtPoint* p = b[0];
    RtPoint c;
    (*p)[0] = &(c[0]);
    (*p)[1] = &(c[1]);
    (*p)[2] = &(c[2]);
    std::cout << p[1] << " " << &(c[0]) << std::endl;
    delete[] b;

    return 0;
}
```

So I just want put in `p[0]`, `p[1]` and `p[2]` the address of `c[0]`, `c[1]` and `c[2]`. My code is wrong but I didn't find a solution.

---

Sorry my fault this code works :)

```
  typedef float RtPoint[3]; 
  RtPoint** b = new RtPoint*[4];
  b[0] = (RtPoint*)new RtPoint;
  RtPoint c;
  b[0] = &c;
```

Edit: yes I've seen my error

Comment: Your code is a real mess. If you say what is your more general problem, I'll try to help

Comment: Not to mention, what do you mean by "my code is wrong"?  Does it fail to compile (what are the diagnostic messages)?  Does it fail to run (and what termination message do you get)?  Does it give unexpected answers (and what are they)?

Comment: The OP has added answers below with more information, and seems to think the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing c++, forget about raw pointers, and use the std::vector.

But if you really insists :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    typedef float RtPoint[3];
    RtPoint** b = new RtPoint*[4];
    b[0] = (RtPoint*)new RtPoint;
    RtPoint* p = b[0];
    RtPoint c;
    (*p)[0] = c[0];
    (*p)[1] = c[1];
    (*p)[2] = c[2];
    std::cout << p[1] << " " << &(c[0]) << std::endl;
    delete[] b;
}
```

By the way, you didn't initialize any variable.

Comment: Please format your code by putting four spaces at the beginning of each line or by using the "code" button in the toolbar. (I've gone in and done this for you here.)